# Fixed length curves in Blender like those found in Zbrush

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, zbrush

Is it possible to move curves in Blender like the curves found in Zbrush? I have a Geometry Nodes modifier applied to a bezier curve and while the Trim Curve node works to keep the length fixed when the transformation is within GN, it does not work correctly when the control points of the initial curve are moved in edit mode. Is there any way to get the curve to move the way it does in Zbrush?

[image: zbrush curve]

Trimming the curve in GN is not a solution

[image: Manually setting a trim curve length]

Comment: Unfortunately no, that's not the way *Geometry Nodes* (currently, and without "hacks") work. There are no loops, there is no physics, it is just a flexible modifier. Blender != Zbrush. Blender != Houdini.

Comment: Disregarding Geometry nodes, is there no way a curve in Blender can behave in a similar way to the way curves move in Zbrush? Parenting, smooth transformations, etc?

Comment: Yes, in principle it would be possible, because basically (almost) everything would be programmable (Python, Add-on, etc.). Honestly, I have unfortunately too little knowledge of other areas in Blender myself, and possibly there is a solution for this (which is not known to me), but with *Geometry Nodes* this will unfortunately not work (at least not without really nasty/unstable/crazy hacks). That much I can say for sure, even if I would like to claim otherwise myself. Reminder: *Geometry Nodes* are designed as a non-destructive modifier.

Comment: I understand. I was given the Trim Curve node as a solution more than once elsewhere and knew that GN was not a real solution to this problem. I am currently looking at using a cloth sim on the bezier curve with hooks as a possible solution in case someone else runs into this issue.